# Arithmetic operation on the subsets of results from a SQL groupby statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, pivot

I have a schema with sex(m/f),state_name(all states of a country), student_name,and education (phd,ms).
I use following query to return total males or females in each category of education for every state.

```
select sex,education,count(*) from mytable group by education,sex;
```

How can I write a query that returns the arithmetic ratio of (male divided by female) for each education in every state?

I am trying to get to query that gives me gender ratio across education tiers for each state (I got count above, but I could not figure out how to do arithmetic division)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select education, sum(sex = 'male') / nullif(sum(sex = 'female'), 0) ratio
from mytable
group by education
```

Comment: Divison by null?

Comment: Sorry, I looked at it inattentively and confused it with IFNULL().

Comment: this should also raise an error when it is NULL  nullif(sum(sex = 'female'), **0**)

Comment: @nbk: look closer. If there is no female for a given education, the `sum(sex = 'female')` produces `0`, and `nullif(sum(sex = 'female'), 0)` turns it to `null`. So the ratio is some number divided by `null`, which produces `null` as a result. No error there.